# Window 10 no option to save preference file using Lyx

Tags: lyx

Using windows 10 and there is no option to save preferences hence there is no preference file. Can you help with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Menu Tools > Preferences > (make changes) > OK or Aplly button

Comment: This does save the preference of that session, however it doesn't generate a preference file in '\Application Data\Lyx2.3' so I can change the colour scheme. See https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ColorSchemes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with windows 10 the relevant folder is hidden. It is accessed by pasting '%AppData%'. Then follow the directions in https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/ColorSchemes to find the preferences file.